# why customer converter do not work in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, converters

Spring mvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Result<String> create(Date beginDate) {
    //...
}
```

client call this api, beginDate parameter used long type

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/foos?beginDate=1459657565000'
```

the response is

```
>Error 400 Bad Request
```

maybe spring mvc cannot convert long to date automatically, so I wrote a customer converter

```
public class LongToDateConverter implements Converter<Long, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(Long source) {
        if (source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date(source);
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new LongToDateConverter());
    }
}
```

then I call this api again, still the same error

```
Error 400 Bad Request
```

and set breakpoint in `convert` method , and found it did not step into this method, So why this converter do not work?

Then I changed it to `POST` method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result<String> create(CouponModel model) {
}
CouponModel:
private Date useBeginDate;
```

Still `Error 400 Bad Request`

Comment: `beginDate` is a parameter, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it'a parameter, but at first it's a property of a `RequestBody` object, and the converter also cannot work

Comment: If it's a parameter, then why isn't it annotated with `@RequestParam`? A GET request has no body.